# Как создать таблицу с пустыми столбцами NULL в peewee (python)

Tags: python, peewee

Может быть простой вопрос, но нигде инфы не нашел. Мне нужно создать таблицу, где будут некоторые столбцы с значением Null. По дефолту peewee не дает это сделать, при заполнении строк ошибка NOT NULL constraint failed: orders.username

Comment: В общем уже нашел решение. Для нужного столбца нужно прописать Field(default=None, null=True) в классе таблицы

Comment: Если Вы нашли решение, перенесите решение из комментария в ответ и пометьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 0):

В общем уже нашел решение. Для нужного столбца нужно прописать Field(default=None, null=True) в классе таблицы